# Openshift CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: openshift

when i try to deploy my project to openshift i get a CrashLoopBackOff error, because pods won't upload this has not allowed me to validate a specific error that i can work with.

one of the messages before generating the error is the following "openshift Container image "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/mservices/kambi:37" already present on machine"

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: the-app
  namespace: the-app
  uid: the-uid
  resourceVersion: '3083693'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2023-03-10T17:29:17Z'
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '1'
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"player-auth","namespace":"mservices"},"spec":{"replicas":1,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"player-auth"}},"template":{"metadata":{"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"app":"player-auth"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"CONFIGPATH","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"CONFIGPATH","name":"config-sec"}}},{"name":"SECURITY","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"SECURITY","name":"config-sec"}}},{"name":"SSLKEY","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"SSLKEY","name":"config-sec"}}},{"name":"SSLCERT","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"SSLCERT","name":"config-sec"}}},{"name":"AUTHKEY","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"AUTHKEY","name":"config-sec"}}},{"name":"AUTHCERT","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"AUTHCERT","name":"config-sec"}}},{"name":"POOLCONFIG","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"POOLCONFIG","name":"pool50-sec"}}}],"image":"192.168.0.176:8445/mservices/player-auth:7","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","name":"player-auth","ports":[{"containerPort":3000}],"resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"500m","memory":"192Mi"},"requests":{"cpu":"0m","memory":"0Mi"}}}],"imagePullSecrets":[{"name":"regcred-nexus"}],"tolerations":[{"effect":"NoSchedule","key":"dedicated","operator":"Equal","value":"mservices"}]}}}}
  managedFields:
    - manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2023-03-10T17:29:17Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            .: {}
            'f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration': {}
        'f:spec':
          'f:progressDeadlineSeconds': {}
          'f:replicas': {}
          'f:revisionHistoryLimit': {}
          'f:selector': {}
          'f:strategy':
            'f:rollingUpdate':
              .: {}
              'f:maxSurge': {}
              'f:maxUnavailable': {}
            'f:type': {}
          'f:template':
            'f:metadata':
              'f:labels':
                .: {}
                'f:app': {}
            'f:spec':
              'f:containers':
                'k:{"name":"player-auth"}':
                  'f:image': {}
                  'f:terminationMessagePolicy': {}
                  .: {}
                  'f:resources':
                    .: {}
                    'f:limits':
                      .: {}
                      'f:cpu': {}
                      'f:memory': {}
                    'f:requests':
                      .: {}
                      'f:cpu': {}
                      'f:memory': {}
                  'f:env':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"name":"AUTHCERT"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:valueFrom':
                        .: {}
                        'f:secretKeyRef': {}
                    'k:{"name":"AUTHKEY"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:valueFrom':
                        .: {}
                        'f:secretKeyRef': {}
                    'k:{"name":"CONFIGPATH"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:valueFrom':
                        .: {}
                        'f:secretKeyRef': {}
                    'k:{"name":"POOLCONFIG"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:valueFrom':
                        .: {}
                        'f:secretKeyRef': {}
                    'k:{"name":"SECURITY"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:valueFrom':
                        .: {}
                        'f:secretKeyRef': {}
                    'k:{"name":"SSLCERT"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:valueFrom':
                        .: {}
                        'f:secretKeyRef': {}
                    'k:{"name":"SSLKEY"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:valueFrom':
                        .: {}
                        'f:secretKeyRef': {}
                  'f:terminationMessagePath': {}
                  'f:imagePullPolicy': {}
                  'f:ports':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"containerPort":3000,"protocol":"TCP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:containerPort': {}
                      'f:protocol': {}
                  'f:name': {}
              'f:dnsPolicy': {}
              'f:imagePullSecrets':
                .: {}
                'k:{"name":"regcred-nexus"}': {}
              'f:restartPolicy': {}
              'f:schedulerName': {}
              'f:securityContext': {}
              'f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds': {}
              'f:tolerations': {}
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2023-03-10T17:31:00Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            'f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision': {}
        'f:status':
          'f:availableReplicas': {}
          'f:conditions':
            .: {}
            'k:{"type":"Available"}':
              .: {}
              'f:lastTransitionTime': {}
              'f:lastUpdateTime': {}
              'f:message': {}
              'f:reason': {}
              'f:status': {}
              'f:type': {}
            'k:{"type":"Progressing"}':
              .: {}
              'f:lastTransitionTime': {}
              'f:lastUpdateTime': {}
              'f:message': {}
              'f:reason': {}
              'f:status': {}
              'f:type': {}
          'f:observedGeneration': {}
          'f:readyReplicas': {}
          'f:replicas': {}
          'f:updatedReplicas': {}
      subresource: status
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: player-auth
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: player-auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: player-auth
          image: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/the-app/player-auth:7'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: CONFIGPATH
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: config-sec
                  key: CONFIGPATH
            - name: SECURITY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: config-sec
                  key: SECURITY
            - name: SSLKEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: config-sec
                  key: SSLKEY
            - name: SSLCERT
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: config-sec
                  key: SSLCERT
            - name: AUTHKEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: config-sec
                  key: AUTHKEY
            - name: AUTHCERT
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: config-sec
                  key: AUTHCERT
            - name: POOLCONFIG
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: pool50-sec
                  key: POOLCONFIG
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 192Mi
            requests:
              cpu: '0'
              memory: '0'
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: {}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred-nexus
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      tolerations:
        - key: dedicated
          operator: Equal
          value: mservices
          effect: NoSchedule
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
status:
  observedGeneration: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2023-03-10T17:29:23Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2023-03-10T17:29:17Z'
      reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
      message: ReplicaSet "player-auth-f55c8cd8d" has successfully progressed.
    - type: Available
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2023-03-10T17:31:00Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2023-03-10T17:31:00Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
```

---

```
oc logs player-auth-f55c8cd8d-kjm9x
Error from server: Get "https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:xxxxx/containerLogs/the-app/player-auth-f55c8cd8d-kjm9x/player-auth": remote error: tls: internal error

[root@virt-okd-srv ~]# oc logs -p player-auth-f55c8cd8d-kjm9x
Error from server: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = malformed header: missing HTTP content-type


oc get pod  player-auth-f55c8cd8d-kjm9x -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/network-status: |-
      [{
          "name": "openshift-sdn",
          "interface": "eth0",
          "ips": [
              "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
          ],
          "default": true,
          "dns": {}
      }]
    k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks-status: |-
      [{
          "name": "openshift-sdn",
          "interface": "eth0",
          "ips": [
              "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
          ],
          "default": true,
          "dns": {}
      }]
    openshift.io/scc: restricted
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-10T17:29:18Z"
  generateName: player-auth-f55c8cd8d-
  labels:
    app: player-auth
    pod-template-hash: f55c8cd8d
  name: player-auth-f55c8cd8d-kjm9x
  namespace: mservices
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: player-auth-f55c8cd8d
    uid: the-uid
  resourceVersion: "3129354"
  uid: the-uid
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: CONFIGPATH
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: CONFIGPATH
          name: config-sec
    - name: SECURITY
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: SECURITY
          name: config-sec
    - name: SSLKEY
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: SSLKEY
          name: config-sec
    - name: SSLCERT
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: SSLCERT
          name: config-sec
    - name: AUTHKEY
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: AUTHKEY
          name: config-sec
    - name: AUTHCERT
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: AUTHCERT
          name: config-sec
    - name: POOLCONFIG
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: POOLCONFIG
          name: pool50-sec
    image: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:xxxx/the-app/player-auth:7
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: player-auth
    ports:
    - containerPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 192Mi
      requests:
        cpu: "0"
        memory: "0"
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        drop:
        - KILL
        - MKNOD
        - SETGID
        - SETUID
      runAsUser: 1000600000
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-7tkp7
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred-nexus
  nodeName: virt-okd-wk2
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1000600000
    seLinuxOptions:
      level: s0:c25,c0
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: dedicated
    operator: Equal
    value: mservices
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure
    operator: Exists
  volumes:
  - name: kube-api-access-7tkp7
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          expirationSeconds: 3607
          path: token
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: ca.crt
            path: ca.crt
          name: kube-root-ca.crt
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            path: namespace
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: service-ca.crt
            path: service-ca.crt
          name: openshift-service-ca.crt
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-03-10T17:29:18Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-03-10T19:49:30Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-03-10T19:49:30Z"
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2023-03-10T17:29:18Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: cri-o://8c302604b6c64bb9db1ddda3002266450f225e297060444ffeb8307d40a2c51c
    image: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:xxxx/the-app/player-auth:7
    imageID: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:xxxx/the-app/player-auth@sha256:3e12239ae3d9e522eaf6bb371be254077b5a82745c60889074e4fd0d204c9d3c
    lastState:
      terminated:
        containerID: cri-o://dfa5de36ceb29a6dd33e345227231bd183e9d17c41dd78e72b5e99b075361fc9
        exitCode: 1
        finishedAt: "2023-03-10T19:44:01Z"
        reason: Error
        startedAt: "2023-03-10T19:43:59Z"
    name: player-auth
    ready: true
    restartCount: 32
    started: true
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2023-03-10T19:49:29Z"
  hostIP: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  phase: Running
  podIP: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  podIPs:
  - ip: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  qosClass: Burstable
  startTime: "2023-03-10T17:29:18Z"
```

Comment: So it seems that your container is crashing once it starts up. What does the application container log say (`oc logs <crashing-pod>` and `oc logs -p <crashing-pod>`)? Why is it exiting (`oc get pod <name> -o yaml`)?

Comment: Add a new entry with the output of the logs commands

Comment: Well, there you can see your error messages, related to TLS and malformed HTTP headers. You should check if your application is configured correctly.

Comment: As Simon mentioned, this is not a OpenShift/Kubernetes issue but a issue with the application in the container image. You can get a debug image with a shell by using `oc debug pod/player-auth-f55c8cd8d-kjm9x`